# ionic 3 app firebase working on browser but not on device

Tags: android, angular, cordova, firebase, ionic3

I'm working on Ionic 3 + firebase application and everything works fine on ionic lab, but when I build the app and install it on a real Android device, the app works fine, only the firebase part is not working. When I click a buton to send some data to the firebase, the loading control appears but still spinning without no success or error with no new record on the firebase. All of this works fine when I run it on ionic lab.

here is my `package.json`

```
{
  "name": "datasaver",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "author": "Ionic Framework",
  "homepage": "http://ionicframework.com/",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "clean": "ionic-app-scripts clean",
    "build": "ionic-app-scripts build",
    "lint": "ionic-app-scripts lint",
    "ionic:build": "ionic-app-scripts build",
    "ionic:serve": "ionic-app-scripts serve"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "5.2.9",
    "@angular/common": "5.2.9",
    "@angular/compiler": "5.2.9",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "5.2.9",
    "@angular/core": "5.2.9",
    "@angular/forms": "5.2.9",
    "@angular/http": "5.2.9",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "5.2.9",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "5.2.9",
    "@ionic-native/background-geolocation": "^4.7.0",
    "@ionic-native/camera": "^4.7.0",
    "@ionic-native/core": "4.6.0",
    "@ionic-native/geolocation": "^4.7.0",
    "@ionic-native/location-accuracy": "^4.7.0",
    "@ionic-native/splash-screen": "4.6.0",
    "@ionic-native/status-bar": "4.6.0",
    "@ionic/storage": "2.1.3",
    "angularfire2": "^5.0.0-rc.10",
    "cordova-android": "7.0.0",
    "cordova-plugin-camera": "^4.0.3",
    "cordova-plugin-device": "^2.0.2",
    "cordova-plugin-geolocation": "^4.0.1",
    "cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard": "^2.1.2",
    "cordova-plugin-ionic-webview": "^1.2.1",
    "cordova-plugin-mauron85-background-geolocation": "^2.3.5",
    "cordova-plugin-request-location-accuracy": "^2.2.3",
    "cordova-plugin-splashscreen": "^5.0.2",
    "cordova-plugin-whitelist": "^1.3.3",
    "firebase": "^5.0.4",
    "ionic-angular": "3.9.2",
    "ionicons": "3.0.0",
    "rxjs": "5.5.8",
    "sw-toolbox": "3.6.0",
    "zone.js": "0.8.26"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@ionic/app-scripts": "3.1.8",
    "typescript": "~2.6.2"
  },
  "description": "An Ionic project",
  "cordova": {
    "plugins": {
      "cordova-plugin-geolocation": {
        "GEOLOCATION_USAGE_DESCRIPTION": "To locate you"
      },
      "cordova-plugin-request-location-accuracy": {},
      "cordova-plugin-whitelist": {},
      "cordova-plugin-device": {},
      "cordova-plugin-splashscreen": {},
      "cordova-plugin-ionic-webview": {},
      "cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard": {},
      "cordova-plugin-camera": {},
      "cordova-plugin-mauron85-background-geolocation": {
        "GOOGLE_PLAY_SERVICES_VERSION": "11+",
        "ANDROID_SUPPORT_LIBRARY_VERSION": "23+",
        "ICON": "@mipmap/icon",
        "SMALL_ICON": "@mipmap/icon",
        "ACCOUNT_NAME": "@string/app_name",
        "ACCOUNT_LABEL": "@string/app_name",
        "ACCOUNT_TYPE": "$PACKAGE_NAME.account",
        "CONTENT_AUTHORITY": "$PACKAGE_NAME"
      }
    },
    "platforms": [
      "android"
    ]
  }
}
```

what seems to be the problem ?